# How does the difficulty scale with more players?

Tags: terraria

I noticed that while fighting the Wall of Flesh that if more people were on the server that it would have more HP.

I assume that this is to make it more balanced when more people play, otherwise 20 people could all just long on and kill any boss super easily.

But how does this scaling work? Is it only for bosses? Does damage increase too or only health? Is it a set amount? A limit to the max health? What if someone is at the other side of the map does it still count or do they have to be near the boss when it spawns? What if someone joins the server after the boss has been spawned?

And mention any other changes that occur due to more players, maybe spawn rate?

Comment: My understanding was that it just made bosses harder, though I don't know if that means more than just higher HP.

Comment: You know, I was just gonna ask this myself :) I've never played multiplayer but was considering it. I do know that bosses drop loot for each player (typically)

Comment: @ydobonebi That's only for expert mode, where a "treasure bag" is dropped which is only visible (and therefore retrievable) by each player

Comment: And just for a weird note, in my SP world, I've looted probably 50+ chests by now, but still haven't found a single heart container.... But I have good armor  and decent weapons so I've not entirely worried.

Comment: @ydobonebi hearts aren't in chests, you can find them while mining, use a metal detector

Comment: @Aequitas I know they aren't, I was comparing the chance of finding one to the other. Not my first time playing :) Last play thru I had found 10 hearts within 2 hours of play.... all luck of hte draw

Comment: Its random and has nothing to do with how many players are on the map.

Comment: @James that's completely wrong. It's not random as it's always the same if the same number of players are there, also I've seen it go up with a different amount of players. See: http://www.ign.com/wikis/terraria/Expert_Mode "Boss health scales based on the amount of players in a game."

Comment: @Aequitas The hearts and treasure chest locations are random and have nothing to do with your question :P

Comment: If you guys don't mind could you find if this is for console too?

Comment: @CrabtasticGoat This was added in version 1.3, which hasn't reached the console version of terraria yet. So your answer would be no.

Comment: Here's best I could find: http://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/expert-mode-multiplayer-boss-health-scaling.27345/ Probably not enough to make an answer out of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your observations for Multiplayer health scaling is only on [Expert Mode](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Expert_mode).

- Only health scales, not damage.
- Only boss health scales. Common enemies have static health (but double compared to normal mode)
- It is per server, so anyone logged in to that server contributes to boss health scaling. This means having more players can potentially be detrimental if they are not actively contributing and carrying their weight towards boss damage.
- According to [this thread](http://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/expert-mode-multiplayer-boss-health-scaling.27345/). The health scales by 130 - 140% of the "one less player" health (ie. for three players it has ~135% the hp that it had for 2 players). If you're looking for specific numbers for a boss you intend to summon, this thread is an excellent place to look.
- It doesn't appear there is a limit to max health.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add to the existing answer that there is in fact a limit to the max health which occurs at 1,498 players when the health is 1,000 times the original health.

This is illustrated on [this webtool](https://output.jsbin.com/neloxon/) which shows the health for all the monsters scaling with a selected number of players.

Comment: Nothing wrong with adding to old questions/answers. Thanks for the extra information! Quite interesting, I'll have to gather 1.5k friends and give the moonlord a go

Comment: You can count me into the 1.5k :p